# How to get form values in meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` however it is something to do with the way how I am calling the event.

Here is a skeleton of my code:

**HTML**

```
<template name="register">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <input type="password" name="password">

        <button type="button" class="register">Register</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Template.register.events({
    'click .register': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var getUser = e.target.username.value;
        var getEmail = e.target.email.value;
        var getPassword = e.target.password.value;

        console.log("user: " + getUser);
    }
)};
```

I feel like there is something to do with the `click event` button class, which is returning no values. I tried using the `submit event`, but I've no idea how to retrieve values.

Answer (score 2):

First up, add the closing `"` after the button type attribute, secondly as this is a form, the type should be `submit`, and then in your event handler you should be listenning for the form submission.  Currently these values don't exist on your target, because its just a button when you need to be listening on the form.

```
<template name="register">
    <form class="form-register">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <input type="password" name="password">

        <button type="submit" class="register">Register</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

So now, we've added a class to the form, updated the button type.  We'll now listen to the forms submission :

```
Template.register.events({
    'submit .form-register': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var getUser = event.target.username.value;
        var getEmail = event.target.email.value;
        var getPassword = event.target.password.value;

        console.log("user: " + getUser);
    }
)};
```

While I've not tested this specifically, this will get you on the right track.  Notice that I've added the template argument to the event handler, as this is the second argument.  This gives you access to the template that you're working with as well, which is slightly nicer than the way you're using the event target right now.   have a look at the docs for [event maps](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) which will talk about this second argument returning a template instance which has a number of useful methods such as find, findAll etc, checkout [template instances here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_inst).

Ultimately my preferred method now for retrieving form values in a submission event, is to bind the form to a [reactive dictionary](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) and access them there, but its a more complex pattern that requires some scaffolding.

Comment: Just to add. Checkboxes have a flaw in Chrome and will return 'on' even though it's not. You'll have to wrap it in jQuery to check it: let checkboxValue = $(event.target.checkboxName).is(":checked");

Answer (score 0):

I would consider getting the values from   the elements directly. So in the click handler function you would have:

```
var name = document.getElementById('idOfUsernameInputField').value;
```

And replicate this for all your fields.

Answer (score 0):

I do like your suggestion @Shi-ii, by using JQuery. But every time when I use JQuery, sometimes my code stop running and says that JQuery is undefined. How can I fix it?

And here is a working solution for my problem. I replace `name` to `id`, so JQuery can access the values.

**HTML**

```
<template name="register">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        <input type="email" id="email" />
        <input type="password" id="password" />

        <button type="button" class="register">Register</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Template.register.events({
    'click .register': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var getUser = $("#username").val();
        var getEmail = $("#email").val();
        var getPassword = $("#password").val();
    }
});
```

Comment: this is going to be a lot slower than accessing the target value, or the already available template instance as you're jumping into the DOM for each value.   Not a problem if this is a quick little prototype, but bad practice none the less.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind, and yes I am prototyping this just playing around with Meteor.js framework. Seems quite nice framework, and I enjoy a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it's good way
Write this js as globally

```
$.fn.searlizeObject = function() {
  var array = this.serializeArray() || [];
  var formData = {};
  array.forEach(function(formElem) {
     formData[formElem.name] = formElem.value;
  });
  return formData;
}
```

Now call this

```
Template.register.events({
  'click .register': function(e) {
   var data = $("#userForm").searlizeObject();
   console.log('my form data is ',data);
});
```

in this you have to write id in your form so we can get all data from form
in your code write this way

```
<template name="register">
<form id="userForm">
    <input type="text" id="username" />
    <input type="email" id="email" />
    <input type="password" id="password" />

    <button type="button" class="register">Register</button>
</form>
</template>
```

Bye Enjoy Coding !!!!

Answer (score -1):

You're not getting the other content bound to your event. Because the button is not the submit input, it's not rolling up all the other inputs with it (as is demonstrated in Meteor documentation).

If your replace your `<button type="button" class="register">Register</button>` with `<input type="submit" class="button register" value="Register">` you will have the desired behavior (where values are passed to the event handler); your handler will look like 
`Template.register.events({
    'submit': function(e){...` and be otherwise unchanged.